# Transfer data from Old to New website

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9, upgrade

I am running 1.7 version of Magento on Website1.com. I am planning to create Website 2, install 1.9 version of magento, then install many new extensions and once that is completed I need to transfer all **customer** and **product** data from website1.com (OLD) to website2.com (NEW)

I am just not sure what exactly shall to transfer,
  Should I transfer **full database** from website1 (OLD) ?
  What **files** should I transfer ?

The way I was thinking of doing it is.
1. Make a copy of my website 1 and update it to magento 1.9. 
2.Then instal new templates, extensions. But It will take me 2-3 weeks to make changes on new website. Once finished how can I transfer most latest customer information that were created during the period I will be developing the new website? (new orders, accounts, subscriptions to newsletters, etc.)

**All I really need is customer data and product data.** **I don't need settings, extensions, and so on.**

Answer (score 3):

While upgrading the magento store from older version to newer version my practice is:

> 1. Take backup of the source code and database of the live site first.
> 2. Download the fresh setup (latest version) of magento from the magento site.
> 3. Then setup the site using the old database and new code.
> 4. Install the extension one after another and solve the errors if encounters during this process.

That's it, it is the ideal process of migrating or upgrading the magento from older version.

And answer to your question, if you don't need the extension, templates etc. than simply only follow first three step, skip the fourth one.

That's it.

Comment: I'd add that you may want to be careful when upgrading from more than a 1.X release to the next.  In particular there have been substantial changes in functionality between 1.7.X to 1.9.1 : The official upgrade guide technically only covers upgrading from 1.8.X to 1.9.X but it follows @sandip.vaghasiya core concept and includes extra steps you may want to consider to help avoid major problems during the process : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_upgrade_details.html